# Why when I try to run tensorflow I have a cuda error?

Tags: tensorflow, pip, importerror

Every time I try to run tensorflow I have the same problem. Even if my code is just this:

`import tensorlfow`

My output is always something like this and I don't know how to fix it. I've tried to uninstall and install it again but nothing happens.

```
2023-04-09 11:55:27.071526: I tensorflow/tsl/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:28] Could not find cuda drivers on your machine, GPU will not be used.
2023-04-09 11:55:27.465762: I tensorflow/tsl/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:28] Could not find cuda drivers on your machine, GPU will not be used.
2023-04-09 11:55:27.472586: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dahe/Nuclear Launch Codes/PYTHON/code_wars.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/home/dahe/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "/home/dahe/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.feature_column import feature_column_lib as feature_column
  File "/home/dahe/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/feature_column/feature_column_lib.py", line 18, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.feature_column.feature_column import *
  File "/home/dahe/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/feature_column/feature_column.py", line 143, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.layers import base
  File "/home/dahe/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.legacy_tf_layers import base
  File "/home/dahe/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras import models
  File "/home/dahe/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/models.py", line 20, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras import metrics as metrics_module
  File "/home/dahe/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/metrics.py", line 34, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras import activations
  File "/home/dahe/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/activations.py", line 18, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import advanced_activations
  File "/home/dahe/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.engine.input_layer import Input
  File "/home/dahe/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/input_layer.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import base_layer
  File "/home/dahe/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 48, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import base_layer_utils
  File "/home/dahe/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer_utils.py", line 31, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.utils import tf_utils
  File "/home/dahe/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/tf_utils.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.distribute.coordinator import cluster_coordinator as coordinator_lib
  File "/home/dahe/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/coordinator/cluster_coordinator.py", line 30, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.distribute import parameter_server_strategy_v2
  File "/home/dahe/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/parameter_server_strategy_v2.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.distribute import cross_device_ops as cross_device_ops_lib
  File "/home/dahe/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/cross_device_ops.py", line 19, in <module>
    import multiprocessing.dummy
  File "/home/dahe/Nuclear Launch Codes/PYTHON/multiprocessing.py", line 9, in <module>
    from multiprocessing import Process, cpu_count
ImportError: cannot import name 'Process' from partially initialized module 'multiprocessing' (most likely due to a circular import) (/home/dahe/Nuclear Launch Codes/PYTHON/multiprocessing.py)
```

Comment: Hi @wade watts, Which tensorflow version have you installed and which System OS are you using? How did you manage to install tensorflow in your system? Please refer to this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#linux) for Tensorflow installation as per your system OS and follow the step by step instructions mentioned along with verifying the Hardware/Software requirements to enable GPU support with Tensorflow.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a CUDA error actually. The name you have given to your Python script is 'multiprocessing.py' which is conflicting with the existing available packages in python.

When TF is being imported, this error is occurring due to conflicting file names.

The error which is the last line in your quoted text is clear enough which states :

> ImportError: cannot import name 'Process' from partially initialized
> module 'multiprocessing' (most likely due to a **circular import**)
> (/home/dahe/Nuclear Launch Codes/PYTHON/**multiprocessing.py**)

Please change your file name and then import TF again to help get rid of this error.